# Capybara and poltergeist test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I been using :firefox drivers for capyabara and this test was passing but when I switch to poltergeist driver the test been failing now with the following error:

Minitest::UnexpectedError: Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "email"

Here is the capybara and poltergeist setup:

```
  def setup
    # FactoryGirl.lint
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.start
    Capybara.run_server = true
    Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
      Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, :js_errors => false)
    end

    Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
    Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist
    Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
    Capybara.app_host = 'http://localhost:4200'
    Capybara.server_port = 3000
    Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5
  end
```

Here is the test:

```
test "User should be able to signin" do
    visit '/'
    wait_for_ajax
    fill_in 'email', with: @user.email
    fill_in 'password', with: @user.password
    assert true
  end
```

So, when I changed the driver to :selenium the test pass with no error.

How do I setup/fix poltergeist to pass this test?

I took screenshot and it shows loading indicator which is a div that is removed in afterModel Ember hook using the following code:

```
_ember['default'].$('.ember-load-indicator').remove();
```

For Ajax calls we have the following function as test helper to wait for ajax calls:

```
  def wait_for_ajax
    Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_wait_time) do
      loop until finished_all_ajax_requests?
    end
  end

  def finished_all_ajax_requests?
    page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').zero?
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's a timing issue... When using poltergeist vs a browser, you can get these weird behaviours, where an element is present, but not really loaded hence the error... An easy way to confirm this is by putting a sleep prior to fill_in email... put `sleep 10` just to be safe...

Additional tip:

To help debug headless tests, consider adding screenshots on failures -

Add this to the end of your Capybara setup:

```
Capybara::Screenshot.register_filename_prefix_formatter(:rspec) do |example|
  "screenshot_#{example.description.gsub(' ', '-').gsub(/^.*\/spec\//,'')}"
end

screenshot_path = "#{PROJECT_ROOT}/screenshot/"
Capybara.save_and_open_page_path = screenshot_path
```

Comment: The filename prefix formatter is not working for my test.

Comment: hmmm, not entirely important, so you could remove the formatter... the point is just save a screenshot so you could view what the headless is seeing... just use the last 2 lines of code...

Comment: screen shot is just showing loading indicator or on other page navbar but no form fields were present there.

Comment: It loads the page partially in poltergeist but work fine in selenium. I think the issue is with phantomjs because I tried to load the same page in phantomjs and I got `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.window.console.error.bind(this.window.console)')`

Comment: Capybara/Phantomjs will explicitly fail the test if there is any JS error, different than selenium... a wild guess would be that on page load, the js error is thrown, and the test stops that at moment, interrupting the page load... It's really hard to give you more suggestions/advises without having the ability to reproduce it myself...

Comment: I can confirm the issue is with phantomjs. Please check the detailed question I asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095210/phantomjs-not-showing-form-fields